# vue.js: Route guard wait for async value

Tags: vue.js, state, vue-router, vuex

As in every application I have a few routes. For example (`router/index.js` excerpt):

```
[{
    path: '/reporting',
    name: 'Reporting',
    component: reporting,
    meta: {
        adminOnly: true
    }
},
...]
```

As you can see in the route definition, when accessing `reporting` the user needs to have admin permissions, which is a property in a vuex store. The problem: This property is async and is of course false when initially accessing in the guard. How can I make my guard wait for it?

Guard:

```
if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.adminOnly)) {
    if (store.getters.userInfo.isAdmin) {
        next()
    } else {
      next('/')
    }
} else {
    next()
}
```

Comment: How and where do you fetch this property?

Comment: It's done in the vuex store on init.

Comment: then you should not start your app before that login action  has resolved. As actions return a promise, that you should be easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about watching the getter, using [store.watch](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html)?

Assuming that your getter returns `null` if the data is not fetched yet.

```js
if (store.getters.userInfo.isAdmin === null) {
    const watcher = store.watch(store.getters.userInfo.isAdmin, isAdmin => {
        watcher(); // stop watching
        if (isAdmin) next();
        else next('/');
    });
}
else if (store.getters.userInfo.isAdmin) next();
else next('/');
```

Comment: It throws `[vuex] store.watch only accepts a function`...?

Comment: Ok I managed to figure it out: It's important that your getter returns an actual function, the getter itself isn't sufficent.
`someGetter(state) {
        return function () {
            return state.xx
        }
    }`

Comment: Is there a pattern to avoid the repeating code ```if store.getters.userInfo.isAdmin) next(); else next('/');``` ? How would you do that ?

Comment: @sandrooco can you please answer here how you solved that error:
It throws [vuex] store.watch only accepts a function

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64511941/vuex-store-watch-only-accepts-a-function-in-vue-router-guard?noredirect=1#comment114071826_64511941