# Vuex store.watch only accepts a function in Vue router guard

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to watch and wait until Vue router guard will get final value from Vuex however it throws
[vuex] store.watch only accepts a function

Here is the code:

```
const isAdmin = _.get(store, 'getters.user/isAdmin', undefined)
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isAdmin)) {
    if (isAdmin === undefined) {
      const watcher = store.watch(isAdmin, isAdmin => {
        watcher() // stop watching
        if (!isAdmin) next({ path: '/not-available' })
      })
    } else if (serv.isAuth() && !isAdmin) {
      next({ path: '/not-available' })
    }
  }
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try not to wait for Vuex - just check if the current user is Admin or not, and move on. If you need an automatic route change as soon as the user becomes Admin - your watcher should probably sit outside of the router guard ...

Comment: @IVOGELOV in that case when you try to refresh or type URL directly it redirects to not found because at that time it's not containing value yet. That's why I used watch, but how can above code be fixed for hiding that error?

Comment: Once the user is authenticated refreshing the page should not make it temporary "not logged" even for a few milliseconds - he/she is either logged-in or not.

Comment: It receives isAdmin getter later not auth

Comment: Since it's async. You are talking about authentication where token is in local storage while role is getting processed via API through the Vuex

Comment: Routes are asynchronous - so your getter can return a Promise, and when that promise resolves - you will call `next()` but when the promise rejects you will call `next("/not-available")`

Comment: Can you please show it with an example or by answer by using the above code?